# $query->result() return null, but $query->num_rows() >0

Tags: php, codeigniter, sqlsrv

I've a function in CI model where return result of query.

```
function ambilDescription($productID)
    {
        $arrayHasil=$this->db->query("select * from tblMstProduct");
        var_dump($arrayHasil);
        if ($arrayHasil->num_rows() > 0) {
            foreach ($arrayHasil->result() as $data) {
                $hasil[] = $data;
            }
            return $hasil;
        }
    }
```

When I echo `$arrayHasil->num_rows()`

> Got 1 row

but when I `print_r($arrayHasil->result())`,

> Got empty **Array()**

This is result of `var_dump($arrayHasil)` :

```
object(CI_DB_sqlsrv_result)#24 (8) { ["conn_id"]=> resource(34) of type (SQL Server Connection) ["result_id"]=> resource(47) of type (SQL Server Statement) ["result_array"]=> array(0) { } ["result_object"]=> array(0) { } ["custom_result_object"]=> array(0) { } ["current_row"]=> int(0) ["num_rows"]=> int(1347) ["row_data"]=> NULL }
```

If i run thats query in SQL Server, i get 1 row.

Comment: From your script you want to `find` some detail right?. Maybe it won't save your problem, But you need this if you want to find some detail. `$arrayHasil=$this->db->query("select * from tblMstProduct where //*Fieldname* = '".$productID."'"`

Comment: Actually,i already use query `select * from tblMstProduct where replace(ProductID,' ','')='".$idProd."'`

Answer (score 2):

Change :

```
if ($arrayHasil->num_rows() > 0) {
```

to

```
if ($arrayHasil->num_rows > 0) {
```

Comment: But i cant get return $arrayHasil->result(), when I print_r($arrayHasil->result()) I get Array().
I need return of query...

Comment: What's the value of `$arrayHasil->num_rows` ?

Comment: $arrayHasil->num_rows = 1

Comment: Check the value of  `print_r($arrayHasil->result_array());`

Comment: Still return empty / Array().

Comment: Run `echo $this->db->last_query();` after `$arrayHasil=$this->db->query("select * from tblMstProduct");` and let me know the result.

Comment: `select * from tblMstProduct`

Answer (score 0):

The right syntax is

```
$arrayHasil->num_rows
```

You can also use this method ( not recommend )

```
$num_results = count($arrayHasil);
```